# pmap_dfr and shifting a vector in data.table

Tags: r, vector, functional-programming, data.table, purrr

I am trying to functionalize my R code, but have run into problems because a lot of my work involves the use of shifted vectors in data.table and pmap_dfr simply does not implement data.table's shift inside the function as expected. I am using R 4.2.2 on a MacOS Venture 13.1 anad the same issue appears in Windows 11. I have presented a minimal working example below.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidytable)

minimal_failing_function <- function(A){
  DT <- data.table(A) 
  DT[ , A:= shift(A, fill = NA, type = "lag", n = 1)] %>% `[`
  return(DT)
}

# works
minimal_failing_function(c(1,2))

# fails
tidytable::pmap_dfr(.l = list(c(1,2)), 
                    .f = minimal_failing_function)
```

The line `tidytable::pmap_dfr` should return:

```
    A
1: NA
2:  1
```

Instead, I get:

```
# A tidytable: 2 × 1
      A
  <dbl>
1    NA
2    NA
```

I am looking for really any solution that will enable me access to `pmap` functionality.

Comment: Perhaps you want `map_dfr` or `pmap_dfr(.l = list(list(c(1,2)), ...)`? The way you use `pmap_dfr` your are looping over the vector `c(1, 2)`, i.e. the result is `c(minimal_failing_function(1), minimal_failing_function(2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the suggestion of stefan, I realized that pmap_dfr wants a list of lists for its input. It automatically unlists the interior list as a vector.

`tidytable::pmap_dfr(.l = list(A = list(c(1,2))), .f = minimal_failing_function)`

gives the desired result.